# Mixing bash and R commands

Tags: r, bash

After reading some other posts, I cannot seem to figure out how to successfully mix bash and R commands.

I need to use a user defined function. The idea I have is below;

```
#!/bin/bash
#fasta conversion
#$ -N convert_fasta
#$ -o convert_fasta.stdout
#$ -e convert_fasta.stderr

module load R/3.4.0
input=/data/dir/path
output=/output/dir/path

#set output directory define function
setwd($output/)
convert <- function(fasta.file, file.name="phylip.phy"){...}

#bash loop to convert files
for file in `ls $input/*.fasta`
do
    convert($file,'$file.phy')
    echo '$file converted to .phy'
done
```

However, this doesn't seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `bash` does not recognize the lines`setwd($output/)` and
`convert <- function(fasta.file, file.name="phylip.phy"){...}` they should be run in `r`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like below, just make sure to pay attention to variables names on bash and R side. \$output is escaped to avoid bash interpreting it. I leave to you the interaction between R and bash :), i.e. if you want to use an R value on bash side.

```
#!/bin/bash
#fasta conversion

RScript -e <<<EOFR
    module load R/3.4.0
    input=/data/dir/path
    output=/output/dir/path

    #set output directory define function
    setwd(\$output/)
    convert <- function(fasta.file, file.name="phylip.phy"){...}
EOFR
```

Check [this page](https://github.com/IARCbioinfo/R-tricks#use-rscript-to-run-r-from-bash) also.